# Gerar PDF com fonte específica

Tags: c#, asp.net, itextsharp

Tenho um relatório que já funciona. Preciso mudar a fonte para "Garamond"(já instalada).
As referências encontradas falam sobre outras propriedades mais flexíveis, com por exemplo, alterar a fonte "por família" [tuto 1](http://help.market.com.br/csharp/pdf_-_cabecalho_e_rodape.htm), ou ainda removendo uma marca-d'água(que também pode ser texto) [tutorial do code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686994/Create-Read-Advance-PDF-Report-using-iTextSharp-in).

Um exemplo do contexto é que a Times New Roman é chamada nominalmente, já que o enumerador da classe [Font](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font(v=vs.100).aspx) já possui a mesma relacionada:

```
Font timesBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, fontSize_small, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
Font timesNormal = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, fontSize_small, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
```

Preciso obter uma forma de gerar o pdf passando, por exemplo, o nome da fonte(Garamond
, Curlz, etc.) Um bom motivo para utilizar a fonte Garamond seria a economia de tinta, já que ela tem os pixels "mais espaçados" e por isso, gasta-se menos tinta.

Answer (score 2):

Solução:

```
// Se a fonte não está registrada
if (!FontFactory.IsRegistered("Garamond"))
{
     // Registro a fonte
     FontFactory.RegisterFamily("Garamond", "Garamond", @"C:\Windows\Fonts");
     // Registro o diretório(não tinha funcionado até tentar isso...)
     FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();                
}                

// Faço a atribuição normalmente
Font garamondBold = FontFactory.GetFont("Garamond", 12, 1); 
Font garamondNormal = FontFactory.GetFont("Garamond");
```

Amostra:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Valeu pessoal